# How to consider only the elements <>0 of the month of January (in Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Here's an example of my problem:
[image: my_problem]

To find all elements for January (including `=0` values) I used the following formula which works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Table1[DATE])=MONTH(1&P18))*(Table1[DATE]<>""))
```

where `P18` = `"GENNAIO"` --> (JANUARY)

How do I know the number of records that are `>0` and which are ONLY for January (also highlighted in green)?

Is there a formula that automatically returns this result (5)?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Table1[DATE])=MONTH(1&P18))*(Table1[DATE]<>"")*(Table1[AMOUNT]>0))`

Comment: @Scott Craner, it works! It was easier than expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
=SUM(IF( (MONTH(B3:B17)=1)*(C3:C17>0),1,0))
```